# SQL Query Generated by Rails #find method

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

There is an Article model with id, title, created_at, and updated_at columns in the database and no additional logic in the model.  In the Rails console, the `find` method generates the following query:

```
Article.find(1)
# Article Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

I was surprised to find that this query raises a syntax error when it's run in the rails db console:

```
$ rails db
sqlite> SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]];
Error: near "[["id", 1]": syntax error
```

I was also surprised to see `LIMIT 1` in the query.  The primary key must be unique, so isn't it obvious that only one result will be returned?

Recap of my questions:

1. Why isn't the `find` method generating 'valid' SQL (i.e. SQL that
   can be pasted in the Rails db console and work)
2. Why is `LIMIT` included in the `find` query.

Answer (score 1):

1. The SQL is not wrong. Rails is showing you what is being injected at the end. It is essentially converting that SQL statement to this:

   SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
2. With find, you are only looking for a single row with the primary key you give. Ruby ensures that what is found should only be a single row. Since you have an article id with one, it will return that data.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object

Comment: 1. Can you elaborate on this sentence "Rails is showing you what is being injected at the end"?  I've only heard of SQL injection in the context of security.  The query you wrote is closer to what I'd expect the Rails console to show.  2. There is a database constraint that the id is unique, so can you see why I am confused that there is a check for this?  If the database doesn't let you make two records with the same id, when is the LIMIT useful?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm on my iPad so typing is limited. 1. The output in the rails console using find is what Active a Record is doing in rails. If you check the URL I supplied, you will see that the SQL being shown is the equivalent if what I posted in the answer. 2. As I said previously, limit is just an assurance. It doesn't need to be there, but Rails wants to be absolutely sure that only one record is returned.

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't the find method generating 'valid' SQL (i.e. SQL that can be pasted in the Rails db console and work)

The key thing is the output which you are seeing is not for copying and pasting into database console. It is just there so it will give you some sense what it is going inside. I guess if you map the values appropriately it will be good then. Also, if you are interested in finding the sql of a give `ActiveRecord` object, you can call [`to_sql`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql) in it.

> Why is LIMIT included in the find query

The [`find`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) method takes any number of arguments. since, you passed one argument, It is `rails` responsibility to give you back 1 record. It might be the cases that the `id` may appear more than one time so just to avoid all such bad scenarios they are appending `limit 1`.

If you pass multiple arguments say `find(1,2,3)` it won't append `limit` clause, since in this case you are getting `Array` instead of `model`.